# Magento 2.4.2 credit memo view not working properly

Tags: creditmemo, refund

I'm coming to you, because I tested the credit memo functionality on my client's site. I noticed that the view does not load all the CSS and JS (see screen)

[image]

When I go into the order to create the credit memo (sales → order) everything works fine. Once I request it, when I'm on the credit memo page (sales ⇾ credit memo) I don't have a design anymore

I don't know how I could debug this.

If you have an idea I would be grateful

If I am not clear, please let me know

Thanks
Hugues

Comment: Share your log from console and system/ exception when you load the page otherwise we won't guess the issue ^^

Comment: I have the same issue. Did an online credit memo with partial refund of sale price. Did u find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

On debug.log i have this :

[2022-11-25 14:40:54] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://xxxxxx.fr/xxxxxxx/admin/index/index/key/3axxxxxxa59c343b6951f3ce5e9a644704xxxxxxx13212c0df1ad9e20f/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []

[2022-11-25 14:40:56] main.INFO: Remove on item with id Magezon_Core::extensions was processed [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:02] main.INFO: Remove on item with id Magezon_Core::extensions was processed [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []
[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.01067590713501,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":636280,"realmem_start":199753728,"emalloc_start":186687688} [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

[2022-11-25 14:41:04] main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a static files issue or there is a PHP error somewhere in the page.

Try to deploy the static files first.

```
bin/magento s:s:d -j 4
bin/magento c:f
```

Also check your console in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Flush the Magento cache if you are using Varnish or Redis please clear that cache and try again. If not working redeploy and try again and share the result.